# ModuleNotFound Error in Python 3.6 when using fake_useragent

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

[Trying to import python module fake_useragent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LpCS.png)

[Command prompt stating that it has already been installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNhdn.png)

Anybody knows how come I still cannot import the fake_useragent module in python even though I have already installed it?

Comment: we have not nearly enough information to debug this problem. best guess, you installed the package in a different python environment to the one you run the command line from.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, I have solved the problem. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the module but it still did not work. I tried to use Jupyter Notebook as well as Pycharm to import the module but I could not. Eventually, I tried to import the module using IDLE, which is the default IDE which comes with downloading and installing Python from python.org and I was successful. Therefore, I suspected that I had accidentally installed two versions of Python on my computer. The problem is that I have already installed Python 3 inside my computer. However, on top of that, I have also installed the Anaconda package, which also installs its own version of Python 3. However, when I use pip to install the fake-useragent module, I am installing it for the original python version. Therefore, when I use Jupyter notebook which is part of the Anaconda package, I could not input the module. I could not import it for Pycharm as well since I used the Anaconda interpreter as Pycharm's default interpreter. After I have uninstalled Anaconda and changed the default interpreter for Pycharm under settings back to the original version of Python which I have installed, I'm able to import the fake-useragent in python.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, I got a similar problem!